# test names with spaces in xBehave.net?

Tags: .net, tdd, bdd

I'm trying to decide between xBehave and NSpec. One thing I like about NSpec is, if using certain syntax, the test names can be specified as strings with spaces:

```
context["when no subscriptions exist"] = () => { ... }
```

That is nice because I'll be typing a lot of these and they'll be sentence length, so CamelCase or underscores would be a relative pain.

Anyone know of a way to do something similar in xBehave.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started using xBehave.net but a typical test would look like this.

```cs
public class CalculatorFeature
{
    [Scenario]
    public void Addition(int x, int y, Calculator calculator, int answer)
    {
        "Given the number 1"
            .Given(() => x = 1);

        "And the number 2"
            .And(() => y = 2);

        "And a calculator"
            .And(() => calculator = new Calculator());

        "When I add the numbers together"
            .When(() => answer = calculator.Add(x, y));

        "Then the answer is 3"
            .Then(() => Assert.Equal(3, answer));
    }
}
```

This example is taken from the quickstart section (https://github.com/xbehave/xbehave.net/wiki/Quickstart). So you can write all your given, when, then or whatever you like in natural language.
I personally use a "establish, when, it should" approach and use the `_()` extension method all around.

A test with my approach would look like this

```
public class ListStorySpecifications
{
    [Scenario]
    public void ListStories(Backlog backlog)
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<string> stories = null;
        "establish an empty backlog"._(() =>
            {
                backlog = new Backlog();
            });

        "when listing all stories"._(() =>
            {
                stories = backlog.GetAll();
            });

        "it should return an empty list"._(() =>
            stories.Should().BeEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I wrote this, I was still learning both. I think what I really wanted was a way to type the test names (`ListStories`) without CamelCase or underscores. I didn't write my question right. Looks like both frameworks use methods for that, so no way to get around it.

Comment: I tend to write pretty short class and method names with xBehave.net omitting the details. and add the details to the strings in the test where I think it is appropriate to give as much detail as necessary.
I don't write any "Feature Introduction" as they call it in the wiki (https://github.com/xbehave/xbehave.net/wiki/Writing-scenarios) I personally think this adds no value and distracts, better invest that time to write your tests well